# PostgreSQL Views: Referencing one calculated field in another calculated field

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns, sql-view

I have the same question as [#1895500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895500/mysql-views-referencing-one-calculated-field-by-name-in-another-calculated-fie), but with PostgreSQL not MySQL.

How can I define a view that has a calculated field, for example:

```
 (mytable.col1 * 2) AS times_two
```

... and create another calculated field that's based on the first one:

```
 (times_two * 2) AS times_four
```

...?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on how heavy the formla is, you could use a subquery:

```
select inner.*, times_two * 2 from
(select mycol * 2 as times_two from table) sub
```

Or rewrite the computation:

```
select mycol * 2, mycol * 2 * 2 from table
```

Answer (score -2):

> Use this statement

```
 
CREATE  VIEW  view_name as  SELECT  column_name*2 as new_col1 , column_name*4 as new_col2  from table_name ; 

select * from view_name ; 

If you want use this view column values. use following things 

create view new_viwe as select new_col1*2 as final_column from view_name ; 

select * from new_view ;
```