# PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns, column-alias

I am having trouble using a calculated column in postgres. A similar code which works in SQL is given below, is it possible to recreate this in `PostgreSQL`?

```
select cost_1, quantity_1, cost_2, quantity_2, 
      (cost_1 * quantity_1) as total_1,
      (cost_2 * quantity_2) as total_2,
      (calculated total_1 + calculated total_2) as total_3
from data;
```

In `PostgreSQL` a similar code returns the error that:

> the column total_1 and total_2 do not exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Views: Referencing one calculated field in another calculated field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385791/postgresql-views-referencing-one-calculated-field-in-another-calculated-field)

Comment: `works in SQL`? You have shown us SQL and then stated that it doesn't work. So what do you mean with "*in SQL*"?

Answer (score 83):

You need to wrap the SELECT statement into a derived table in order to be able to access the column alias:

```
select cost1,
       quantity_1,
       cost_2,
       quantity_2
       total_1 + total_2 as total_3
from (
    select cost_1, 
           quantity_1, 
           cost_2, 
           quantity_2, 
           (cost_1 * quantity_1) as total_1,
           (cost_2 * quantity_2) as total_2
    from data
) t
```

There won't be any performance penalty on that.

(I'm **really** surprised that your original SQL statement runs at all in a DBMS)

Comment: The original post looks like SAS's PROC SQL which does allow this

Comment: I'd like to have a let ... = .... definition as in Haskell here to define a local calculation instead of a subquery. That would be great.
Nevertheless, Thank you for your good answer!

Comment: What's the advantage/disadvantage of wrapping select statement and not using CTE for example? Thanks :)

Comment: @Davita: in Postgres a CTE is optimized differently then a derived table. In most cases (including this one) this doesn't make a difference, so it boils down to personal preferences. Also not everybody is used to CTEs and that would have introduced another level of "complexity" in the answer which I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 73):

If you don't like wraping entire query with outerquery, you could use [`LATERAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) to calculate intermediate `total_1` and `total_2`:

```
SELECT cost_1, quantity_1, cost_2, quantity_2, total_1, total_2,
       total_1 + total_2 AS total_3
FROM data
,LATERAL(SELECT cost_1 * quantity_1, cost_2 * quantity_2) AS s1(total_1,total_2);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=beacb5d90259873ca0d08d2060495332)**

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ cost_1  ║ quantity_1  ║ cost_2  ║ quantity_2  ║ total_1  ║ total_2  ║ total_3 ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║      1  ║          2  ║      3  ║          4  ║       2  ║      12  ║      14 ║
║      3  ║          5  ║      7  ║          9  ║      15  ║      63  ║      78 ║
║     10  ║          5  ║     20  ║          2  ║      50  ║      40  ║      90 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Oh nice. TIL. This is so much nicer for some cases, including mine which is creating a view that does many layers of reference to previous calculations. In-lining repeated calculations is error-prone and nesting subqueries had like 9 levels of nesting for me. The `LATERAL` version is much easier to follow and maintain.

Comment: What is the `s1` in the lateral part here? By trial and error I've found that it can be arbitrary string - why is that required then?

Comment: @RobinNemeth `s1` is alias for derived table. You could use it in `SELECT` like `SELECT  s1.total_1 + s1.total_2 AS total_3`

Answer (score 34):

As a rule, there a two things you need to know about the `SELECT` clause:

- Although it is written *first*, it is evaluated *last*, with the exception of the `ORDER BY` clause. This is why you cannot use any calculated fields or aliases in any other clause (particularly the `WHERE` clause) *except* in the `ORDER BY` clause.
- Calculations in the `SELECT` clause are performed in *parallel*, or at least are handled as if they are. This is why you cannot use one calculation as part of another.

So, the short answer is that you can’t, and that is by design.

The notable exception to this is Microsoft Access, where you can indeed use calculations in subsequent columns and `WHERE` clauses. However, although that is convenient, it’s not actually an advantage: not following the above principals is less efficient. But it’s OK for light duty databases, which is what Access is supposed to be used for.

If you really want re-use calculated results, you will need a separate query, either in the form of a sub-query or as a Common Table Expression. CTEs are much easier to work with, as they are clearer to read.

**Edit**

Here is an example why using calculated columns could cause confusion. In Australia we measure height in centimetres, but there still some places which use the ancient inches (1 in = 2.54 cm).

```
SELECT
    id,
    height/2.54 as height, -- cm -> in
    case when height>175 then 'tall' else '' end as comment
FROM people;
```

Here the `CASE` still uses the original `height` value.

Comment: As an aside, whenever I am dealing with fields with physical units, I always include the unit, where possible in the schema, but if I'm building some complicated queries, I would alias `height` as `height_cm` as an example. It's less verbose but always helpful whenever you may be needing to do that conversion between metric and imperial.

Answer (score -1):

```
select cost_1, quantity_1, cost_2, quantity_2, 
      cost_1 * quantity_1 as total_1,
      cost_2 * quantity_2 as total_2,
      (cost_1 * quantity_1 + cost_2 * quantity_2) as total_3
from data;
```

Comment: Not in case of postgres!

Comment: it does not work for sure, not in postgresql

Answer (score -5):

You're trying to use column aliases in an expression. If a system allows you to do that it's just syntactic sugar. This should work in any SQL dialect.

```
select 
 cost_1
,quantity_1
,cost_2
,quantity_2
,cost_1 * quantity_1 as total_1
,cost_2 * quantity_2 as total_2
,(cost_1 * quantity_1) + (cost_2 * quantity_2) as total_3 

from data;
```

Comment: Not in case of postgres!