# Reuse doctrine alias in select clause

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following SELECT clause in Doctrine (the query itself is created using query builder):

```
u.username,
MAX(p.score) as highscore,
SUM(pc.badgeCount) as badgeCount,
(SUM(pc.badgeCount) / :badgeSum) AS probability,
(-LOG(RAND()) * probability) as weight
```

(`p` is an alias for the main entity, `pc` is a joined one)

This gives me an error message from MySQL:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'probability' in 'field list'
```

How can I reuse the created aliases within the same SELECT clause?

Comment: You need a subquery. I don't know if doctrine has any elegant way to write subqueries - But I would rather calculate `probability` and `weight` in PHP either way.

Comment: The correct non-hackish way is subquery/cte [using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query) or simply copy-paste expression definition and it will work with all flavours of SQL.The mechanism you are searching for is called [lateal column reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334543/amazon-redshift-lateral-column-alias-reference).

Answer (score 4):

I would not call it "reuse".  Instead, I would call it "use".

You cannot use an alias until the `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `ORDER BY` clauses.

An alternative *might* be to use an @variable:

```
u.username,
MAX(p.score) as highscore,
SUM(pc.badgeCount) as badgeCount,
@prob := (SUM(pc.badgeCount) / :badgeSum) AS probability,
(-LOG(RAND()) * @prob) as weight
```

The "AS" part still provides the column name for displaying and for those later clauses.  Meanwhile, `@prob` provides a value "immediately".

I say "might" because I think that such use of @variables is going away.  The order of evaluation of the `SELECT` elements is probably "undefined" in the standard.  The use shown above depends on the elements to be done in lexical order.

Comment: I always love reading your answers -- I just have a hard time shedding the mental image that you are _THIS_ Rick James: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJB0BkJlbbw&list=PLIYT3J6kwPPE7OcT5uieDrzQZoxXWfjEA

Comment: Thanks! Looks good. Only problem is how to get this in a QueryBuilder, because it looks like Doctrine ORM doesn't support MySQL variables. Any idea?

Comment: Does it handle `CALLs` to Stored Procedures?