# Sum multiple columns and sum their alias in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Is it possible to `sum` the columns and sum again?

```
select 
id,
sum(t2.col) as cola,
sum(t3.col) as colb,
sum(t4.col) as colc,
sum(cola + colb + colc) as total
from t1
left join t2 on t2.id = t1.t2fk
left join t3 on t3.id = t1.t3fk
left join t4 on t4.id = t1.t4fk
group by t1.id
```

something like this

```
sum(cola + colb + colc) as total
```

Comment: You cannot reuse the alias in the same query level. The mechanism you would like to use is called: [lateral column alias reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334543/amazon-redshift-lateral-column-alias-reference)

Comment: Why `sum(cola + colb + colc)`? Do you mean `cola + colb + colc`? Clarify what you want.

Comment: Iam looking for this  `sum(t2.col + t3.col + t4.col) as total`

Comment: As a 4th column? Or as a last row of the results?

Comment: last row result

Answer (score 1):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select id, sum(t2.col) as cola, sum(t3.col) as colb, sum(t4.col) as colc
  from t1
  left join t2 on t2.id = t1.t2fk
  left join t3 on t3.id = t1.t3fk
  left join t4 on t4.id = t1.t4fk
  group by t1.id
)
select c.*, null as total
from cte as c
union all
select null, null, null, null, sum(cola + colb + colc)
from cte
```

For earlier versions:

```
select id, sum(t2.col) as cola, sum(t3.col) as colb, sum(t4.col) as colc, null as total
from t1
left join t2 on t2.id = t1.t2fk
left join t3 on t3.id = t1.t3fk
left join t4 on t4.id = t1.t4fk
group by t1.id
union all
select null, null, null, null, sum(t2.col + t2.col + t2.col)
from t1
left join t2 on t2.id = t1.t2fk
left join t3 on t3.id = t1.t3fk
left join t4 on t4.id = t1.t4fk
```

In case there are `null`s in the columns `t2.col`, `t3.col` and `t4.col`, instead of

```
sum(t2.col + t2.col + t2.col)
```

use:

```
sum(t2.col) + sum(t2.col) + sum(t2.col)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with aliases, but you can do it by re-writing the SELECT clauses, like this:

```
select 
id,
sum(t2.col) as cola,
sum(t3.col) as colb,
sum(t4.col) as colc,
sum(t2.col) + sum(t3.col) + sum(t4.col) as total
from t1
left join t2 on t2.id = t1.t2fk
left join t3 on t3.id = t1.t3fk
left join t4 on t4.id = t1.t4fk
group by t1.id
```

There will be no performance penalty (i.e. MySQL will not "re-summarize" the three columns to produce the total)

Comment: "MySQL will not "re-summarize" the three columns" - Is there any reference which can backup that statement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by using a nested query.

```
SELECT id, cola, colb, colc, SUM(cola + colb + colc)
  FROM  (
      SELECT id, SUM(a) cola, SUM(b) colb, SUM(c) colc
        FROM whatever ...
       GROUP BY id
        ) subquery_alias
 GROUP BY id
```

Most servers' query planning modules do a good job optimizing these sorts of queries built from sub queries.

**Pro tip** Format these nested queries carefully in your source code so you, or somebody else, can read them easily years from now.