# Does snowflake has function LISTAGG(column_name [, delimiter] ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE )?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

It seems "ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE" feature is not available in snowflake which goes with LISTAGG in Oracle.
Is there a alternate function or workaround to it?

Comment: [Snowflake - LISTAGG with LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77208016/5070879)  - different scenario because it based on number on elements than character limit but maybe somebody will find it useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select listagg(str, ', ') within group (order by id) as listagg
from (
    select id
        ,str
        ,sum(length(str))over(order by id) as s_str
    from (
        select * from values(1,'abcdef'),(2,'dfgsdfh'),(3,'jgeg'),(4,'ergegr') s(id,str)
    )
    qualify s_str <= 20
);
```

gives the values with total (prior to delimiters)

```
,sum(length(str)+2)over(order by id) as s_str
```

allows you to take the size of the delimiter ', ' into account

or if you want some truncating suffix like `'...'` then this will do that..

```
select listagg(str, ', ') within group (order by id) as listagg
from (
    select id
        ,s_str <= 20 as underlimit
        ,iff(underlimit, str, '...') as str
    from (
        select id
            ,str
            ,sum(length(str)+2)over(order by id) as s_str
        from (
            select * from values(1,'abcdef'),(2,'dfgsdfh'),(3,'jgeg'),(4,'ergegr') s(id,str)
        )
    )
    qualify underlimit or row_number() over (partition by underlimit order by id) = 1
);
```

giving

```
LISTAGG
'abcdef, dfgsdfh, ...'
```

to rewrite as CTEs which does not change anything...

```
with data as (
    select id
       ,str
       ,sum(length(str)+2)over(order by id) as s_str 
    from values 
        (1,'abcdef'),
        (2,'dfgsdfh'),
        (3,'jgeg'),
        (4,'ergegr') 
        s(id,str)
),  check_length_and_limit as (
    select id
        ,s_str <= 20 as underlimit
        ,iff(underlimit, str, '...') as str
    from data
    qualify underlimit or row_number() over (partition by underlimit order by id) = 1
)
select listagg(str, ', ') within group (order by id) as listagg
from check_length_and_limit;
```

Comment: Good idea of using qualify! Two comments: nesting code with 4 level inline vies makes it  hard to read, a version with multiple CTEs should be preferred.  Second: `select id
        ,s_str <= 20 as underlimit
        ,iff(underlimit, str, '...') as str` does Snowflake allow for reusing alias at the same level(here underlimit) aka [lateral column alias reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334543/amazon-redshift-lateral-column-alias-reference)?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda done..normally I write CTE and they take heaps more space, and don't change anything once you know how to read them... but sure if you like to see it in CTE form. And yes once's a alias is defined you can use it in Snowflake.. but window functions and aggregations play well, but you sometimes needs some select from brackets to scope stuff, which is why I used four layers as you note.. i started with just one level but it didn't like that...

Comment: Wow!! It worked like a charm. I wish snowflake had such functions that would have been much easier.
Thanks for the help.