# Snowflake - LISTAGG with LIMIT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, string-aggregation

Snowflake allows to concatenate string across multiple rows by using aggregate/windowed [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg) function. Sometimes we just need first few occurrences per group. Similar to `GROUP_CONCAT with LIMIT`:

```
SELECT grp, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       GROUP_CONCAT(col ORDER BY col SEPARATOR ',' LIMIT 3) AS first_3 
FROM tab
GROUP BY grp;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/m6x1cBwY)**

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(grp TEXT, col TEXT) AS
SELECT * FROM VALUES 
  ('Grp1', 'A'),('Grp1', 'B'),('Grp1', 'C'),('Grp1', 'D'), ('Grp1', 'E'),
  ('Grp2', 'X'),('Grp2', 'Y'),('Grp2', 'Z'),('Grp2', 'V'),
  ('Grp3', 'M'),('Grp3', 'N'),('Grp3', 'O');
```

For provided sample input the expected result is:

| grp | cnt | first_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Grp1 | 5 | A,B,C |
| Grp2 | 4 | X,Y,Z |
| Grp3 | 3 | M,N,0 |

The idea is to find simple way of controlling number of rows considered for `LISTAGG` without affecting other aggregate functions and using subqueries like:

```
SELECT grp, 
  COUNT(*) AS cnt,
  LISTAGG(CASE WHEN rn <= 3 THEN col END, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY col) AS first_3
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY col) AS rn
      FROM tab)
GROUP BY grp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative to aggregate string concatenation is creation of array and transforming it to string afterwards. [MIN_BY/MAX_BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by) allows to choose number of rows for returned array.

```
SELECT grp, COUNT(*) AS cnt, ARRAY_TO_STRING(MIN_BY(col, col, 3), ',') AS first_3
FROM tab
GROUP BY grp;
```

Output:

[image]

Here: `ARRAY_TO_STRING` and `MIN_BY` is effectively an equivalent of `LISTAGG` with  `LIMIT`.

---

It also works well for windowed scenario, if all rows are required:

```
SELECT grp, 
  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY grp) AS cnt, 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(MIN_BY(col, col, 3) OVER(PARTITION BY grp), ',') AS first_3
FROM tab
ORDER BY grp;
```

[image]

If `LISTAGG(DISTINCT ...)` is expected then `ARRAY_DISTINCT` can be added:

```
SELECT grp, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_DISTINCT(MIN_BY(col, col, 3)), ',') AS first_3_distinct
FROM tab
GROUP BY grp;
```