# Filter rows after string operation on unnested array

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Why is this situation failing? 
What's the neatest way to solve my problem?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable foo
WHERE ARRAY_AGG(SUBSTRING(UNNEST(foo.array), 'abc(.*?)xyz')) 
    && ARRAY['ElementA','ElementZ']
```

My table has an array column, which contains unparsed Strings. What I am doing here is parsing those, element by element, and then reaggrouping again into an array, so I can compare if the processed array contains any of my expected elements

But it returns:

> ERROR:  column "foo.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used
>   in an aggregate function

Do I really need to group by all the columns? Shouldn't the where filter be virtual uniquely? IS there maybe a way to deal virtually with the unnest/nest operations without affecting the rest of the query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help others figure out what you are *trying* to do.

Comment: The thing is that all of this is a simplification, I am not sure it is valuable to focus too much on a mock scenario, which will be simpler

Comment: @Whimusical Preparing sample data and desired output is **always** valuable and  helps to  provide accurate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I really need to group by all the columns? Shouldn't the where filter be virtual uniquely? Is there maybe a way to deal virtually with the unnest/nest operations without affecting the rest of the query

You could use `JOIN LATERAL`:

```
SELECT foo.*
FROM myTable foo
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(SUBSTRING(s.t, 'abc(.*?)xyz')) AS r
              FROM UNNEST(foo."array") s(t)
             ) sub 
   ON sub.r && ARRAY['ElementA','ElementZ'];
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6878f0c20fb5e325f69e8f750ad8ab45)**

---

Another "uglier" way is to use subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(SUBSTRING(s.t, 'abc(.*?)xyz')) AS r
              FROM UNNEST(foo."array") s(t)
             ) r
  FROM myTable foo
) x
WHERE r && ARRAY['ElementA','ElementZ'];
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=788c36497ac427f6f2c6cb6dda169484)**

More info [PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query/36530228)