# postgresql alias and use alias in select

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to do

```
SELECT column1 + column2 as add_of_two_columns
    , add_of_two_columns + column3 as another_add_of_two_columns 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY (add_of_two_columns * 2) / another_add_of_two_columns;
```

Unfortunately, I get errors in my SELECT clause and in my ORDER clause that columns (my aliases) don't exist.

How can I make this work?

Comment: [PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36530228/5070879) Subquery or duplicating expression or `LATERAL JOIN`. Feel free to choose the one that suits you best

Comment: Explanation why you can't use both at the same level: [All-at-Once Operations](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx#All-at-Once)