# Select constants as pseudo columns and do arithmetic on pseudo columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, relational-database

I want to do something like this:

```
select 999 as price, 0.1 as tax_rate, 
price*tax_rate as tax_amount, tax_amount+price as total
from Dual;
```

on an Oracle database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `CROSS APPLY`(Oracle 12c):

```
select price, tax_rate, tax_amount, tax_amount+price as total
from Dual
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 999 AS price, 0.1 AS tax_rate FROM dual) s
CROSS APPLY (SELECT price*tax_rate AS tax_amount FROM dual) s2;

select price, tax_rate, tax_amount, tax_amount+price as total
from Dual
,LATERAL (SELECT 999 AS price, 0.1 AS tax_rate FROM dual) s
,LATERAL (SELECT price*tax_rate AS tax_amount FROM dual) s2;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7a87e511844df4cc5cbc7b6ec38394d7)**

You could not refer to defined columns at the same level(`SELECT`) but with  `CROSS APPLY`/`LATERAL JOIN` you could create a chain of calculated columns without using subqueries.

Similar approach: [PostgreSQL using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query/36530228#36530228)