# is it possible to use the output of two rows in order to calculate the third row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT .......

---a long calculation-- AS MARGIN,

---calculation--- AS SALES

FROM          .....
where .....
GROUP BY .....
order by REV desc;
```

Now i want to add another column which is "Margin percent" which is
MARGIN/SALES.
How can i do it without calculating MARGIN and SALES  again ?
so the output table will be:

```
| Margin | SALES | Margin percent
```

Comment: [using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query) -- CROSS APPLY/LATERAL if not supported then wrapping with subquery will help

Comment: Need to know what database you use "sql" comes in many flavours, each dbms vendor has it's own recipe. You might be able to use a window function if the dbms supports it, or `cross apply` or `lateral join`, all depending on which dbms

Comment: i"m using ms sql

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your current query up in a `derived table` (i.e. the subquery). Do the percent calculation on its result.

```
select margin, sales, margin * 100.0 /sales
from
(   
    SELECT .......

    ---a long calculation-- AS MARGIN,

    ---calculation--- AS SALES

    FROM          .....
    where .....
    GROUP BY .....
) dt
```

Comment: _dt_ is just a table alias. Shouldn't be needed, but some products require it. You can try without it, or chose another table alias.