# Refer to other alias column title in the same select query

Tags: postgresql, psql

doing:

```
select t1*t2 as t, t*1  from (select target1,target2 from signals)
```

Gives:

```
column "t" does not exist
```

How can I refer to t at the same time I am declaring it in the select query?

Comment: [PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query/36530228#36530228)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Oh nice, thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query)

Comment: Sure.. Thanks  my friend

Comment: Are `t1` and `t2` referring to `target1` and `target2` respectively?

Comment: @RodrigoFormighieri if you already got the answer you can answer it by yourself or delete this question..