# How to write "replace" once in a SQL query having 3 times like operator

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Here is my sql query. I don't want to write the "replace" 3 times. How can I optimize it ?

```
select * from table1 where col1='blah' AND 
(
replace(replace(col2,'_',' '),'-',' ') LIKE ? OR 
replace(replace(col2,'_',' '),'-',' ') LIKE ? OR 
replace(replace(col2,'_',' '),'-',' ') LIKE ?
)
```

Comment: Do you have `INDEX(col1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use a column alias in the HAVING clause even without any aggregation:

```
select *, replace(replace(col2,'_',' '),'-',' ') as col2_replace
from table1
where col1='blah'
having col2_replace like ?
    or col2_replace like ?
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  select *, replace(replace(col2,'_',' '),'-',' ') AS r
  from table1 
  where col1='blah' 
) s
WHERE r LIKE ? OR r LIKE ? OR r LIKE ?
```

---

Or `LATERAL`:

```
select *
from table1
  ,LATERAL(SELECT replace(replace(col2,'_',' '),'-',' ')  AS r) s
where col1='blah' 
  and (s.r LIKE ? OR s.r LIKE ? OR s.r LIKE ?)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=720ff6467ec97fb5dfd7c762a6c49b09)**

I prefer the second approach because there is no need for introducing outer query. This feature was added in version 8.0.14.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36530228/5070879)
- [CROSS/OUTER APPLY in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467105/5070879)

Comment: Is LATERAL supported in mysql ?

Comment: @HariDas Of course it is :) Please check provided link and demo

Comment: Will writing 3 times, i.e my original query will be faster or the 2nd query you wrote will be faster ?

Comment: @HariDas "faster" is relative. You should compare execution plans for both queries. Query optimizer could do a lot of transformations depending on order of execution(normally it would calculate the function once per row). From developer perspective `LATERAL` is much better: DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a tendency to materialize subqueries -- not only is this overhead for reading and writing a temporary table but it can also affect the use of indexes in a more complicated query.

Here are three alternative solutions that do not require subqueries.

If `?` does not contain wildcards, then the simplest method is:

```
 replace(replace(col2, '_', ' '), '-', ' ') in (?, ?, ?)
```

If it does, then change logic to use a single regular expression pattern:

```
 replace(replace(col2, '_', ' '), '-', ' ') regexp ?
```

You can also explicitly adjust the pattern in the query:

```
 replace(replace(col2, '_', ' '), '-', ' ') regexp
    concat('(',
           replace(replace(?, '_', '.'), '%', '.*'), ')|(',
           replace(replace(?, '_', '.'), '%', '.*'), ')|(',
           replace(replace(?, '_', '.'), '%', '.*'), ')'
          )
```