# Avoid repeating expression in SELECT list and WHERE clause

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a basic query that fetches rows from data dumped from google autocomplete containing the place_id, formatted address and a json column which contains the entire json object. I believe I am using Postgres 10 or 11.

```sql
WITH 
    t AS (
        SELECT place_id,formatted,full_json 
        FROM addresses_autocomplete 
        WHERE json_array_length(full_json) > 7
    ), 
    r AS (
        SELECT short_name FROM regions WHERE regions.country_id = 1
    )
SELECT DISTINCT ON(place_id) 
    t.full_json->5->'short_name' AS state, 
    t.full_json->7->'long_name' as postal_code, 
    full_json->3->'short_name' AS city 
FROM t 
INNER JOIN r ON r.short_name = t.full_json->5->>'short_name' 
WHERE t.formatted=$1;
```

Is there any way to write my query so that `t.full_json->5->'short_name'` does not get repeated?

Comment: You  could use [`LATERAL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36530228/5070879)

Comment: No. Look at https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations or https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-is-the-order-of-execution-of-an-sql-query for example. `from` and `where` clauses executes before `select`. In some (most?) DBMSs you can use aliases from `select` (or just column numbers) in `order by` and `group by` clauses.

Comment: There is [no Postgres version 9.11](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). And there is no need to believe. Use `SELECT version();`.

Comment: Well I couldn't recall what version I had been using.

Comment: Are you not using it anymore? The arsenal of available tool depends on the Postgres version. It's just a coincidence that there is a solution for this with very basic tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [@Abelisto commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149907/using-as-property-from-select-in-where-statement-in-postgresql-query/58151061#comment102684405_58149907), you cannot refer to `SELECT` list expressions from the `WHERE` (or `JOIN`) clause of the same command because expressions in the `WHERE` clause are evaluated first. Consider the sequence of events:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

You need a subquery or CTE to avoid repeating the expression. **However**, your expressions are not exactly the same to begin with. You extract a simple text as `json` and use the same as actual `text` in the JOIN clause. The extraction is tricky by itself. Consider:

```
test=# SELECT json '"foo"' #>> '{}';
 ?column?
----------
 foo
```

[**`#>>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) is the operator to ...

> Get JSON object at specified path as text

Passing an empty array as path (`{}`) extracts `text` from the simple `json` text. Related:

- [Postgres: How to convert a json string to text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215216/postgres-how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-text/31757242#31757242)

Now, to ***avoid repeating*** the extract path, extract `state` in the CTE or in a subquery and apply the above expression in the outer `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.place_id)
       a.state
     , a.full_json -> 7 -> 'long_name'  AS postal_code
     , a.full_json #> '{3,short_name}'  AS city    -- alternative syntax, btw.
FROM  (
   SELECT full_json -> 5 -> 'short_name' AS state  -- once!
        , full_json
   FROM   addresses_autocomplete
   WHERE  json_array_length(full_json) > 7
   AND    formatted = $1
   ) a
JOIN   regions r ON r.short_name = t.state #>> '{}'  -- key element!
WHERE  r.country_id = 1
-- ORDER  BY place_id, ??? -- put expression(s) here to get deterministic pick
```

Equivalent to your original. While being at it I simplified the query, inlined the CTEs (don't use CTEs unless needed before Postgres 12, they typically add cost) and added `ORDER BY`, which will be required to get a deterministic result.

About `DISTINCT ON` & `ORDER BY`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

---

But are you sure you want `postal_code`, `city` and `state` as type `json`? That's an odd requirement.

Also, the above query may not produce the best query plan. The key to performance is to support the most selective predicates with optimal indexes. Repeating an expression hardly matters. You might want this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.place_id)
       a.full_json #>> '{5,short_name}' AS state
     , a.full_json #>> '{7,long_name}'  AS postal_code
     , a.full_json #>> '{3,short_name}' AS city
FROM   addresses_autocomplete a
JOIN   regions r ON r.short_name = a.full_json #>> '{5,short_name}'  -- back to repeating
WHERE  a.formatted = $1
AND    json_array_length(a.full_json) > 7
AND    r.country_id = 1
-- ORDER  BY a.place_id, ???
```

Comment: In fact, using a CTE, which is an optimization fence, led to a noticeable performance decline in my case