# How to remove delimited sections from text in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, replace, string-function

I want to eliminate some text pattern from a string, my string has a pipe delimiter, and the parameters do not always follow each other.

This is my string

```
TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3
```

I want to eliminate `TType=SEND` and `URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1`

Therefore my final result should be

```
Status=OK|day=3
```

What i have tried. Not working  **in postgresql** .

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3', 
'(TType=.*?(\||$))|(URL=.*?(\||$))', '')
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It has failed to eliminate the URL parameter within its delimiter

Comment: The string is dynamic not always with same content, so TType does not always occur at the start

Comment: Ah, ok, I see, these params are consecutive.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew any luck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer:

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE(
 REGEXP_REPLACE('TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3',
  '(TType|URL)=[^|]*\|?', '','g'),
'\|$', '');
```

Explanation:

1. The `.*?` part in your pattern, although not greedy, consumes colons as well, so doesn't behave as intended. This is fixed by `[^|]*` that consumes any non colon character, zero or more times.
2. Then you would also need to add the global flag 'g', in order to replace all occurences of pattern, as described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).
3. Finally, in case a parameter you need to eliminate occurs last (since the parameters can appear in any order), you need to add an extra replacement step to eliminate a residual colon at the end of the string.

For example without the extra step, the following

```
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE('Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3|TType=SEND',
  '(TType|URL)=[^|]*\|?', '','g');
```

produces

```
Status=OK|day=3|
```

while, addding the extra step, the following

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE(
 REGEXP_REPLACE('Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3|TType=SEND',
  '(TType|URL)=[^|]*\|?', '','g'),
'\|$', '');
```

produces the desired

```
Status=OK|day=3
```

Answer (score 3):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d23057bdd7e36177a6253409f6837015)

```
SELECT
    string_agg(elements,'|')                                                 -- 3
FROM mytable,
    regexp_split_to_table(mystring, '\|') as elements                        -- 1
WHERE split_part(elements, '=', 1) = ANY(ARRAY['TType', 'URL']) IS NOT TRUE  -- 2
```

1. Split the string into params like `A=B`. Move every into a separate record
2. Split these elements at the `=` character and filter for elements without key = `TType` or `URL`
3. Finally aggregate all these first splits to a string list.

Comment: If i could have this in the select statement, before `..from`

Comment: Which part? The WHERE or the regexp_split_to_table?

Comment: Works with subquery: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=658de7b1e559f6cee35147d06d1c7b81

Comment: There you can use a FILTER clause instead the WHERE clause: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ccf7c15b283aa62e0dac6e3382172613

Comment: The solution is okay however i would want to have the solution between `select` and `from` . i.e. `select (the solution here) from table`

Comment: Please see my comments before yours

Comment: Sure upvoted, solution is okay however it does not fully satisfy my question. since i would want the solution to be within `select and from`

Comment: Well, I fear, with THIS ways, there's no solution. Maybe someone delivers a regex...

Comment: Sure, regex could work, maybe. if no answer then i will have to go your way

Answer (score 2):

[The S-Man's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210479/5070879) is a working one

> Sure upvoted, solution is okay however it does not fully satisfy my question. since i would want the solution to be within select and from

If this is a "mandatory" requirement then I see the following options:

1. create a function
2. use LATERAL JOIN to enclose all the logic into one place, related [PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query/36530228#36530228)

The final query may look like:

```
SELECT t.*, s.result
FROM t
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(elements,'|') AS result
   FROM regexp_split_to_table(t.col, '\|') as elements
   WHERE split_part(elements, '=', 1) = ANY(ARRAY['TType', 'URL']) IS NOT TRUE) s ON TRUE
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cca1d1d9d83206b33d554e21b7fd420b)**

Alternatively by using subquery in SELECT list:

```
SELECT t.*, 
(
   SELECT string_agg(elements,'|') AS result
   FROM regexp_split_to_table(t.col, '\|') as elements
   WHERE split_part(elements, '=', 1) = ANY(ARRAY['TType', 'URL']) IS NOT TRUE
) AS result
FROM t
```

**[db<>fiddle demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ffc11ae36e2dcbd92653f854b00a4403)**

Answer (score 2):

The following regex based solution should do the trick:

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(
         'TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3', 
         '(TType|URL)=[^|]*(\||$)', '', 'g'), '|')
-- outputs:
-- Status=OK|day=3
```

How the pattern works:

```
(TType|URL)=[^|]*(\||$)
|-----------|----|-----
1           2    3
```

1. the pattern starts consuming if any substring starts with either `TType` or `URL` followed by `=`
2. the pattern consumes any character that is *not* `|`
3. the pattern consumes either the | or the end of the string

The `g` flag is described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE) as

> flag g specifies replacement of each matching substring rather than only the first one.

It is necessary here as we want to replace all substrings that match our pattern.

Finally, sometimes a single `|` character might remain at the end of the string. Any trailing `|` character is `trimmed` from the result using `TRIM`

Comment: Thanks, `(Status|TType|day)=[^|]*(\||$)` i have tried and it is ok. is it possible to remove the pipe at the end from above regex. this is the result `URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|`

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa, see updated answer. using the `TRIM` function, the trailing `|` character can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

There were a few issues with your attempted regular expression:

1. Even though a non-greedy `.*?` match was used, this could still include pipe symbols. This can be rectified by using a matcher that allows anything except a pipe symbol (this can be greedy): `[^|]*`
2. It should use the `'g'` flag to replace all occurrences, not just the first.
3. It only looks for the pipe at the end, not at the beginning. This means it will leave the last pipe intact at the end if it matches the string after the last pipe (i.e. `URL=...` in your example).

From addressing the points above, here is a working version:

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('TType=SEND|Status=OK|URL=min://j?_a=3&ver=1.1|day=3', '((Status|TType)=[^|]*[|]|[|](Status|TType)=[^|]*)', '', 'g')`

**Rextester demo:** https://rextester.com/CYBP40923

Comment: great soln `(Status|TType|day)=[^|]*([|]|$)` why is it that this leaves a pipe in the end of the result.

Comment: It's because the regex is only looking for pipe symbols (or alternatively the end of the text) at the *end* of each match not at the beginning. If you need to deal with that then unfortunately you will need some repetition as you need to be looking for the pipe at either the start or the end but not both: `((Status|TType|day)=[^|]*[|]|[|](Status|TType|day)=[^|]*)`. (Have now edited my answer accordingly).