# How to use percentile_conts with multiple quantiles in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, quantile, percentile-cont

I currently have a query that works like so:

```
select AVG(t2 - t1) as delay,
       percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by (t2 - t1)) as q25,
       percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by (t2 - t1)) as median,
       percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by (t2 - t1)) as q75,
       p.bool1,
       p.cat1
from people p
group by p.bool1, p.cat1
order by p.cat1,p.bool1
```

However, I read on the postgres functions aggregation page:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html

That I should be able to specify multiple quantiles:

```
percentile_cont(fractions) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sort_expression)  double precision[]  double precision or interval    array of sort expression's type     multiple continuous percentile: returns an array of results matching the shape of the fractions parameter, with each non-null element replaced by the value corresponding to that percentile
```

I'd like to use this so I don't recalculate the t2 - t1 for every quantile.  What's the right syntax to get multiple quantiles?  Would I need a subquery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'd like to use this so I don't recalculate the t2 - t1 for every quantile

Lateral join could help in such scenario:

```
select AVG(t2 - t1) as delay,
       percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by s.col) as q25,
       percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by s.col) as median,
       percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by s.col) as q75,
       p.bool1,
       p.cat1
from people p
,LATERAL(SELECT t2 - t1 AS col) s
group by p.bool1, p.cat1
order by p.cat1,p.bool1;
```

Related: [PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query/36530228#36530228)

---

Array are defined as: `ARRAY[0.25, 0.5, 0.75]`  or `'{0.25, 0.5, 0.75}'::double precision[]`

```
select AVG(t2 - t1) as delay,
   -- 1
   percentile_cont(ARRAY[0.25, 0.5, 0.75]) within group (order by (t2 - t1)) as q25,
   -- 2
   percentile_cont('{0.25, 0.5, 0.75}'::double precision[]) 
   within group (order by (t2 - t1)) as q
       p.bool1,
       p.cat1
from people p
group by p.bool1, p.cat1
order by p.cat1,p.bool1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=abe2d7f53108a572290f49e87b00b67d)**

---

> Is there an easy way to inline specify the names of each of the resulting percentile fields as they had been with q25, q50, q75, etc

```
WITH cte AS (
    select AVG(t2 - t1) as delay,
       percentile_cont(ARRAY[0.25, 0.5, 0.75]) within group (order by (t2 - t1)) as q,
           p.bool1,
           p.cat1
    from people p
    group by p.bool1, p.cat1
)
select cte.*, q[1] AS q25, q[2] AS q50, q[3] AS q75
from cte
order by cat1,bool1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc4aa6fa9d9799e5f777818e15ddc6c8)**

Comment: Thanks!  The array declaration was the key insight I needed.  I didn't understand why it wasn't working with a variadic list of doubles!

Comment: Is there an easy way to inline specify the names of each of the resulting percentile fields as they had been with q25, q50, q75, etc?

Comment: @Mittenchops Yes, you could access each element of result array and add an alias