# How could I correctly write PostgreSQL query for percentages?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, postgresql-11

i have tables like this

```
 companies                 users
id|   name              id |  company_id|  name
1 | AIRBUS             101 |    2       | Martin
2 | BOEING             102 |    1       | Ray
3 | CHRYSLER           103 |    3       | Richard
```

and I have to get as results  :
Company/count of users/percentage of users.

I tried that

```
SELECT companies.name as Societe
, COUNT(users.id) as nbre_utilisateurs
, nbre_utilisateurs*100/(SELECT SUM (nbre_utilisateurs) as pourcentage 
FROM users
JOIN companies ON companies.id=users.company_id
GROUP BY Societe
ORDER BY nbre_utilisateurs DESC
```

and get as response :

> `Query Error: error: syntax error at or near ";"`

Then my question is : What ";" ? There's not any ";" here ...
I've been trying many other syntaxes but did not manage to get Company/count of users/percentage of users.

I have to find 2 different ways of making it, and determine how to make it the fastest.
I'm really new to PostgreSQL and ask for your kind help :)

Comment: this is wrong `, nbre_utilisateurs*100/(SELECT SUM (nbre_utilisateurs) as pourcentage `

Comment: you have 3 `(` and only 2 `)` - when you get an error like that one and are using subqueries, one of the first things to check is that you properly closed all brackets. The system is implicitly adding a `;` at the end of the query, and since the subquery was never closed that's where it's erroring out.

Comment: Rene, you may want to do `COUNT(users.id) *100.0` instead of `COUNT(users.id) *100` if you want decimals in your result, otherwise it'll give you the percentage truncated to whole digits - `1*100/3=33` vs `1*100.0/3=33.333333`

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong `nbre_utilisateurs*100/(SELECT SUM (nbre_utilisateurs) as pourcentage`

```
SELECT companies.name as Societe
, COUNT(users.id) as nbre_utilisateurs
, COUNT(users.id) *100/(SELECT count(*) from users) as pourcentage 
FROM users
JOIN companies ON companies.id=users.company_id
GROUP BY Societe
ORDER BY nbre_utilisateurs DESC
```

also you can use window function :

```
SELECT companies.name as Societe
, COUNT(users.id) as nbre_utilisateurs
, COUNT(users.id) *100/ sum(count(users.id)) over () as pourcentage 
FROM users
JOIN companies ON companies.id=users.company_id
GROUP BY Societe
ORDER BY nbre_utilisateurs DESC
```

Comment: Hi Eshirvana and thank you for your answer :)
I get `Query Error: error: column "nbre_utilisateurs" does not exist`
But it's called right ? I don't get it

Comment: @René where is "nbre_utilisateurs" column? in which table?

Comment: @René you're trying to access an alias in a subquery - that won't actually work

Comment: The column does not exists. because `nbre_utilisateurs` is an alias, not a column name. You can replace `nbre_utilisateurs*100/(SELECT....` by `COUNT(users.id)*100/(SELECT...`

Comment: @René see updated answer

Comment: @René `COUNT(users.id)*100/(SELECT COUNT(users.id) from users) as pourcentage` you don't need to sum the subquery, it recounts the entire table on its own.

Comment: @eshirvana Thank you man, you're the best. So kind of you. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you have a missing `)` in your query which is the source of the error. Even if you fix that your query will still not work, because you are referencing a calculated column `nbre_utilisateurs` within the same `SELECT` statement. There are a few ways of solving this as outlined in this Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query/36530228).

I'd personally re-write the query to calculate the users per company in a CTE, and then have a separate query to calculate the market share percentage.

```sql
-- CTE for calculating users per company
with anon_1 as (
    SELECT companies.name as Societe,
        COUNT(users.id) as nbre_utilisateurs
    FROM users
        JOIN companies ON companies.id = users.company_id
    GROUP BY companies.name
)
-- Final query to get company, number of users, market share
SELECT anon_1.Societe,
    anon_1.nbre_utilisateurs,
    (
        anon_1.nbre_utilisateurs * 100 / SUM (anon_1.nbre_utilisateurs)
    ) as pourcentage
from anon_1
GROUP BY anon_1.Societe
ORDER BY anon_1.nbre_utilisateurs DESC
```

Comment: Thank you @CadentOrange for your time :)
I have to admit I get `Query Error: error: column "anon_1.societe" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` and I don't understand why

Comment: Just seen this. I've fixed the query.